# Open Specific View Controller on Click of Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am recieving push notification from backend but unable to go to specific controller from the click of push notification.

My Code is:

In appDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* payLoad = [[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"appsInfo"];

    if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"COURSE_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPAnalyticsViewController"]; //or the homeController
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
       // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"ASSESSMENT_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OUSTCardsViewController"]; //or the homeController
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

In didReceiveRemoteNotification method I have Written:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification");

    if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"COURSE_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPAnalyticsViewController"]; //or the homeController
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
       // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"ASSESSMENT_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OUSTCardsViewController"]; //or the homeController
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` you should set the root view controller.

And then on `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` you should use `pushViewController` or `performSegue`.

For e.g. -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIViewController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPAnalyticsViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
}
```

And now when you receive notification -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"COURSE_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPAnalyticsViewController"]; 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController]
    } else if ([[payLoad objectForKey:@"type"]  isEqual: @"ASSESSMENT_DISTRIBUTE"]){
        UIViewController * viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone_Storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OUSTCardsViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController]
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? what do you get in the logs? it was just dummy code, you also have to check the navigation controller instance, if you are using proper instance?

Comment: I can' t debug because the certificate is of production and debug mode is not working because of backend issue.

Comment: You can add log and check the console, what are values you are getting, if you are going inside if clause?

Comment: Logs are not working in distribution mode. Help me out If it so.

Comment: NSLog should work, you can see those logs in distribution mode.